# Run unit tests and IT tests separately while launching pre-integration and post-integration

Tags: java, maven, unit-testing, spring-boot, integration-testing

I want to be able to run unit tests and integration tests separately. I have tried using different configurations of fail-safe and verify which do work BUT they when using fail-safe or verify in the command line (mvn failsafe:test, mvn surefire:verify, etc.), it does not launch my pre-integration and post-integration phase which I need for my integration test.

Here is my POM:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
    <mainClass>com.nulogix.billing.App</mainClass>
    </configuration>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>pre-integration-test</id>
            <goals>
                <goal>start</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
        <execution>
            <id>post-integration-test</id>
            <goals>
                <goal>stop</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.18.1</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <goals>
                <goal>integration-test</goal>
                <goal>verify</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.0-M3</version>
    <configuration>
        <skipTests>false</skipTests>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Comment: What kind of pre-integration-test parts do you need to run integration tests with Spring Boot ?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot run one phase or a bunch of phases separately.

Either you make all plugin calls on the command line, or you run the whole build from beginning to post-integration.

If, on the other hand, your main goal is to skip certain plugins during the build, you can achieve this through `skip` parameters or profiles.